# How to customize Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

How to put space in between option value of `Zend_Form_Element_Select`
Expected result as follows,

http://jsfiddle.net/HLbQE/

Tried as follows,

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'parent_id', array(
      'label' => 'Select Category',
      'multiOptions' => array('0'=>'Gents','1'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jeans','2'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sunglass','3'=>'Ladies','4'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jeans','5'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sunglass')
));
```

but fails,

Any help please

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [optgroups](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP)? ZF handles this natively by using a nested array for the multi-options, eg

```
$options = array(
    'Gents' => array(
        1 => 'Jeans',
        2 => 'Sunglass'
    ),
    'Ladies' => array(
        3 => 'Jeans',
        4 => 'Sunglass'
    )
);
```

Updated demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/HLbQE/1/

Comment: +1 That might be an even better solution in this case indeed.

Comment: here how can i select gents or ladies? :-(

Comment: @Kyathi do you actually need to? Unless you write your own view helper, I think you're out of luck

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'parent_id', array(
      'label' => 'Select Category',
      'multiOptions' => array('0'=>'Gents','1'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jeans','2'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sunglass','3'=>'Ladies','4'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jeans','5'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sunglass'),
      'escape' => false // <-- added 
));
```

I seems this will not work indeed, as reported in this, still unresolved, issue:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5351

Comment: @Kyathi: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: it will print &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jeans in option value